# Qual é a diferença entre as dataTypes do Ajax no jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Estou aprendendo jQuery e preciso saber a diferença entre as dateTypes do Ajax.

```
dataType: "xml"

      dataType: "json"

            dataType: "script"

                   dataType: "html"
```

Como isso influencia na execução do script e retorno do resultado?

Comment: As respostas abaixo estão decentes, mas ninguém respondeu: ... **Como isso influencia na execução do script e retorno do resultado** ...

Answer (score 14):

> Fonte: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

**XML:** Retorna um documento xml que pode ser processado via JQuery. o retorno deve ser tratado como nodes XML

```
$.ajax({
 url : "xml.xml",
 dataType : "xml",
 success : function(xml){
        $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
            var titulo = $(this).find('title').text();
            console.log(titulo);
        });
    }
});
```

**JSON:** Avalia a resposta como JSON e retorna um *objeto javascript*

```
$.ajax({
    url : "json.php",
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(data){
                 for($i=0; $i < data.length; $i++)
                   console.log(data[$i])
              }
});
```

**JSONP:** Requisição muito parecida com JSON, com a diferença de que é possível realizar chamadas através de domínios diferentes, com um parametro adicional chamado callback.

```
//json.php
{ foo: 'bar' }
```

--

```
//jsonp.php
meucallback({ foo: 'bar' })
```

--

```
$.ajax({
    url : "www.outrosite.com/jsonp.php",
    dataType : "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback : "meucallback"
});
```

--

```
function meucallback(obj)
{
    console.log(obj);
}
```

**SCRIPT:** Carrega um script externo em formato de string

```
//externo.js
alert("OLA")
```

--

```
$.ajax({
    url : "externo.js",
    dataType : "script",
    success : function(scriptString){
               eval(scriptString); //executa o script retornado
              }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

A resposta do @JeffersonSilva é bastante descretiva, porém gostaria de apresentar uma resposta mais técnica.

Os dataTypes do jQuery se baseam em [*MIME Types*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME). Esses são usados no HTTP header, onde se refere ao `Content-Type`.

Sendo assim, o dataType de script se refere a `application/javascript`.

Seguindo o lógico, seria algo assim:

```
dataType  MIME type
--------  ----------
xml       text/xml ou application/xml
json      application/json
script    application/javascript
html      text/html
```