# Entregar array PHP vindo de ajax a campo HTML

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Bom, estou usando `$.ajax` para recuperar um `json_encode()` em um arquivo **PHP**.

Nesse arquivo é *populado* um **formulario**:

```
$html .= "
        <input type='hidden' id='dados' value='" . $relatoriosGr . "' />
        <button id='btnRelatorio' class='button'>Gerar Relatório</button>
    ";
echo json_encode( $html );
```

O problema está aqui:

```
<input type='hidden' id='dados' value='" . $relatoriosGr . "' />
```

Quando no final desse arquivo php passa pelo json_encode dá erro pois `$relatoriosGr`  é um array **PHP**.

Se eu tentar jogar ele assim:

```
echo json_encode( array ($html, $relatoriosGr) );
```

até vai mas quando chega no **$.ajax** de volta, acabo tendo problema para tranferir esse **array** encodado para o campo criado.

```
success: function (result) {
    $(".resposta").html(result[0]);
    $("#dados").val(JSON.parse(result[1]));
}
```

Como resolver isso?

**ADD**: **array** `$relatoriosGr` no **PHP**

```
Array
(
    [17] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [data] => 2019-03-01
                    [ofetas] => 22.65
                    [decisoes] => 6
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [data] => 2019-03-03
                    [ofetas] => 55.33
                    [decisoes] => 3
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [data] => 2019-03-05
                    [ofetas] => 30.45
                    [decisoes] => 2
                )

        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [data] => 2019-03-02
                    [ofetas] => 78.39
                    [decisoes] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [data] => 2019-03-05
                    [ofetas] => 30.00
                    [decisoes] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Como está esse array? Poderia mostrar? Dê um `print_r($relatoriosGr)` e mostre o resultado

Comment: é um array bem grande para postar aqui

Comment: Mas ele tem campos? É um array associativo? Ou é [0] => array("valor1","valor 2"), [1] =>array("outrovalor1","outrovalor 2")

Comment: ok, postei a saida na pergunta

Comment: Certo... E você precisa inserir todo o array no campo value do input certo? Mas então porque usar o `json_encode` e depois usar `JSON.parse` do javascript se ele é um input hidden ?

Comment: Você está convertendo o array pra string direto, vai dar erro mesmo. Tenta: `value='" . json_encode($relatoriosGr) . "'`

Comment: Não apenas isso... Ele está tentando inserir um objeto no value de um input... aqui: `JSON.parse(result[1])` isso dará um erro ou mostrará apenas `object`

Comment: exatamente isso que está acontecento mas invetido. JSON.parse(result[1]) dá vazio e apenas result[1] dá object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha, eu acho que o melhor modo de você reaproveitar as informações inseridas no input seria assim:

**php**

```
$html .= "
        <input type='hidden' name='dados' id='dados' value='" . json_encode($relatoriosGr). "' />
        <button id='btnRelatorio' class='button'>Gerar Relatório</button>
    ";
echo $html;
```

**javascript**

```
success: function (result) {
    $(".resposta").html(result);
}
```

---

Quando for postado o formulário, basta você recuperar as informações assim, no php ou no javascript:

**php**

```
$array = json_decode($_POST['dados'], true);
```

**javascript**

```
var str = $("#dados").val(); // pega a string em json
var obj = JSON.parse(str); // transforma em objeto (tipo de vetor)
```

No javascript você pode fazer o envio da string para o php via `ajax` e transformar em array com `json_decode`.

Comment: Quando faço echo $html; no PHP o código para. Tive que encodar novamente para prosseguir echo json_encode ($html); Fiz errado?

Comment: Acho que o seu `ajax` espera uma resposta em `json`... Retire essa parte do javascript que funcionará. Creio que é a linha que contém o `dataType`... retire essa linha que funcionará

Comment: ok, tinha me esquecido disso. Obrigado! mas que tipo de dados estou recbendp agora senão json. só para adiconar lá?

Comment: @CarlosRocha seria HTML! `text/html` mas eu não sei como deve ser inserido isso no ajax... Vou ver depois e te passo.

Comment: @CarlosRocha é `dataType:'html'` ..... veja aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/77358/15361